# Nginx PHP FDM issue with server

Tags: php, linux, nginx, digital-ocean

I was having bad gateway error so I followed this http://www.nginxtips.com/502-bad-gateway-using-nginx/ and many other articles to configure and after sometime I started receiving 503 error. And now website is now opening

In my nginx log it says

```
2015/09/03 20:49:09 [error] 8060#0: *42716 connect() failed (110: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: domainname.com, request: "POST /xmlrpc.php HTTP/1.0", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "domainname.com"

2015/09/03 20:56:02 [error] 15796#0: *57 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: domainname.com, request: "POST /xmlrpc.php HTTP/1.0", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "domainname.com"
```

Php-fdm log

```
[03-Sep-2015 21:04:28] NOTICE: [pool www] child 16171 started
[03-Sep-2015 21:04:28] WARNING: [pool www] child 15884 exited on signal 11 (SIGSEGV) after 499.074068 seconds from start
[03-Sep-2015 21:04:28] NOTICE: [pool www] child 16172 started
[03-Sep-2015 21:42:00] NOTICE: Finishing ...
[03-Sep-2015 21:42:00] NOTICE: exiting, bye-bye!
[03-Sep-2015 21:42:00] NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 17943
[03-Sep-2015 21:42:00] NOTICE: ready to handle connections
[03-Sep-2015 21:44:06] NOTICE: Finishing ...
[03-Sep-2015 21:44:06] NOTICE: exiting, bye-bye!
```

When I run this command I get

dmesg | grep php

```
[21010128.307479] php5-fpm[15840]: segfault at 1000721 ip 00000000006c2197 sp 00007fffad5b3de0 error 4 in php5-fpm[400000+73d000]
[21010129.349165] php5-fpm[15852]: segfault at 1000721 ip 00000000006c2197 sp 00007fffad5b3de0 error 4 in php5-fpm[400000+73d000]
[21010129.854832] php5-fpm[15853]: segfault at 1000721 ip 00000000006c2197 sp 00007fffad5b3de0 error 4 in php5-fpm[400000+73d000]
[21010130.735855] php5-fpm[15864]: segfault at 1000721 ip 00000000006c2197 sp 00007fffad5b3de0 error 4 in php5-fpm[400000+73d000]
[21010130.938996] php5-fpm[15847]: segfault at 1000721 ip 00000000006c2197 sp 00007fffad5b3de0 error 4 in php5-fpm[400000+73d000]
[21010131.116782] php5-fpm[15854]: segfault at 1000721 ip 00000000006c2197 sp 00007fffad5b3de0 error 4 in php5-fpm[400000+73d000]
[21010131.543774] php5-fpm[15869]: segfault at 1000721 ip 00000000006c2197 sp 00007fffad5b3de0 error 4 in php5-fpm[400000+73d000]
[21010131.851328] php5-fpm[15851]: segfault at 1000721 ip 00000000006c2197 sp 00007fffad5b3de0 error 4 in php5-fpm[400000+73d000]
[21010131.891856] php5-fpm[15866]: segfault at 1000721 ip 00000000006c2197 sp 00007fffad5b3de0 error 4 in php5-fpm[400000+73d000]
```

Thank you

Comment: Your logs don't seem to be spanning the same time periods? Also, it looks like php-fpm is existing after a 500 second POST. What are you submitting? Are YOU the one submitting data? Not enough to go on here, I'm afraid...

Comment: the same is being repeated again again so I got the chunks of data from the log file so there can be a mismatch in timestamp. Can you let me know what else should I provide?